# Datepickers with different font sizes and options on the same page

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery UI's datepicker to display calendar. In my requirement i need to show 2 different calendars with different options i.e datepicker1 should have year / month / days selection and datepicker2 should have only year / month selection and also both with different font sizes.

I tried the following CSS

```
 .ui-datepicker-calendar{
   display:none;
 }
```

But the above CSS style makes to disappear the calendars for both date pickers.
Please let me know your ideas about this

Comment: Give a different `class` attribute to each and style each class accordingly? Your question doesn't give us enough information to work with.

Comment: Please specify which plugin you are using.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Which plugins do you use? What did you tried?

Comment: I have used JQuery DatePicker.

Comment: Do you mean you have used JQuery UI DatePicker ? just to  clarify for everyone here ... Also, if you problem is solved, please select an answer.

Comment: Yes. I am using JQuery UI DatePicker. My problem is not yet solved. Atleast is there any ugly hack to this?

Comment: what have you tried? did you try any of the suggested solutions ? what have you got ?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the css to datepicker2 :

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="firstStyleDatePicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="secondStyleDatePicker"></p>
```

if this still doesn't work (the css doesnt apply) you might wannt try !important .

Comment: Firstly: IDs must be unique in HTML. Secondly: how do you know this is the markup which is being used?

Comment: i followed : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ , this is the way to use datepickers, unless you customize jQuery code they must have the same id ( and my guess was that he didnt customize it)...

Comment: Nowhere does the question specify that jQuery UI is being used.

Comment: huh, thats right... i'm almost sure that i saw jquery-ui in tags

Comment: Actually he does say in his question "JQuery date pickers" so i think he deso use jQuery UI

Comment: As I mentioned on shaunakde's answer: I could make a date picker with jQuery myself which doesn't use jQuery UI. jQuery UI's date picker isn't the only one out there, either. This question should be closed as "lacking information to diagnose the problem", otherwise you're just guessing what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:12px;
}
```

Add this under the stylesheet of jquery-ui.

Comment: Nowhere does the question specify that jQuery UI is being used.

Comment: Jquery datepicker uses Jquery-UI!

Comment: I could make a date picker with jQuery myself which doesn't use jQuery UI. jQuery UI's date picker isn't the only one out there, either.

Comment: The question mentions jQuery Datepickers; lets wait for OP to spcify in detail.

Comment: This solution will alter both datepickers font size as 12px